# How to match html or js once in minimatch?

Tags: javascript, node.js, glob

I'm writing glob pattern for gulp watch, and want to rebuild on each html or js change

```
# my first variant
> minimatch('src/app/app.js', 'src/app/**/*.(js|html)')
false # not working
> minimatch('src/app/app.js', 'src/app/**/*.+(js|html)')
true # this works
> minimatch('src/app/app.jsjs', 'src/app/**/*.+(js|html)')
true
# but also this works:
> minimatch('src/app/app.jsjsjsjsjs', 'src/app/**/*.+(js|html)')
true
```

How to do in properly, meaning match html or js only once, like in regular expressions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you can use this:

```
minimatch('src/app/app.js', 'src/app/**/*.{js,html}')
```

Answer (score 1):

You are asking it to match one or more of `(.js|.html)` you need to use `@` to match only one

```
minimatch('src/app/app.js', 'src/app/**/*.@(js|html)')
```